# Alternate method to solve $\sqrt{11\sqrt{11\sqrt{11...4\, \text{times}}}}$

Tags: nested-radicals

**Question :**

> What is the value of
> $$\sqrt{11\sqrt{11\sqrt{11...4\,\text{times}}}}$$

I did it by solving square root one by one.
$$\sqrt{11\sqrt{11\sqrt{11\times11^\frac{1}{2}}}}$$
$$\sqrt{11\sqrt{11\sqrt{11^\frac{3}{2}}}}$$
$$\sqrt{11\sqrt{11\times{11^\frac{3}{4}}}}$$
$$\sqrt{11\sqrt{11^\frac{7}{4}}}$$
$$\sqrt{11\times{11^\frac{7}{8}}}$$
$$\sqrt{11^\frac{15}{8}}$$
$$11^\frac{15}{16}$$

Is there any other way to solve this?

I don't want the complete solution, just tell me the approach.

Comment: I think your method is more or less optimal.  for a (minor) variant:  Rewrite in exponential notation.  There's one $11$ to which the square root is applied exactly once, so that's a factor of $11^{1/2}$.  Then there's one $11$ to which it is applied exactly twice, so that's a factor of $11^{1/4}$.  Continue this way.

Comment: @lulu I didn't get you.

Comment: there was a typo in what I wrote, now corrected.   In the end, you should get $11$ raised to the power $\frac 12+\frac 14+\frac 18+\frac 1{16}=\frac {15}{16}$.  This method makes it easy to see how you'd handle $1000$ iterates, instead of just $4$.

Comment: Oh! It is a sum of geometric progression.

Comment: Exactly.  So you should easily be able to work out the result for $n-$ iterates.  But, really, this is the same as your method...maybe written down in a way that makes the pattern easier to spot.

Comment: But why this works? Can you give me proof?

Comment: My comment is the proof.  Or, if that seems too vague for you, prove it by induction.  Let $a_n$ be the expression with $n$ iterates.  Remark that $a_{n+1}=11^{1/2}\times \sqrt {a_n}$.

Comment: Why do  you think "it seems too vague to me"?

Comment: Well, you asked for a proof where I'd have said that my first comment already was a proof.  I made a guess as to why you were dissatisfied with my initial argument.  In any case, you should be able to make my comment into a proper proof, or use the inductive method I sketched.

Comment: I just love this method(GP). Thanks a lot .

Comment: Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you solve the square roots one by one, but from outer one to inner one, you see it is the sum of geometric sequence.

Answer (score 1):

There is a faster way to solve it, actually:

$\sqrt{11·\sqrt{11·\sqrt{11·\sqrt{11·\color{blue}{11}}}}}
 = \sqrt{11·\sqrt{11·\sqrt{11·11}}}
 = \sqrt{11·\sqrt{11·11}}
 = \sqrt{11·11}
 = 11$

So clearly the extra factor is just $\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\color{blue}{11}}}}}$, since square-root commutes with multiplication on non-negative reals (which implies that in any expression comprising just multiplication and square-roots the number of square-roots in effect is just the number of 'radical lines' above it).

Comment: It is interesting to know alternatives. +1